# Made changes to React component but Laravel shows old component

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I deployed my Laravel website on a server which works just fine. I recently made changes to one of the React components on my local machine, pushed the code to Github and pulled the new code from my server. When I browse my website I still see the old component, not the new edited one. I tried running `npm run dev` and `prod` but that didn't help. Does someone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple layers of cache that you need to clear

```
php artisan view:clear
```

And delete the `public/js/app.js` file and run

```
npm run prod
```

Also, make sure to restart your `opcache` if enabled

Also, purge the cache from Cloudflare or similar service if you're using those

And finally, test your website with a private window or Guest Mode on Google Chrome

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks! I will accept the answer when it allows me to.